# Reading XMLNodeList

Tags: c#, xmlnodelist

I have an odd issue where I am trying to read a node in an xml document but I need to read the nodes inner text after a node that I can find based on the inner text.

I have an xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DataFeedObject xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <TransactionID>a4b0ecc1-2d28-49f4-b9c7-caec861aa80d</TransactionID>
  <ApplicationID>b0926229-3209-4881-8cf3-cf4a88756a7f</ApplicationID>
  <TransactionDateTime>2016-04-25T21:03:49.5805295Z</TransactionDateTime>
  <DataItems>
    <DataItem>
      <Name>Account_Type</Name>
      <Value>Cash</Value>
    </DataItem>
    <DataItem>
      <Name>Account_Type_MarginDetails</Name>
    </DataItem>
    <DataItem>
      <Name>Agent_FirstName</Name>
      <Value>Jane</Value>
    </DataItem>
    <DataItem>
      <Name>Agent_IDNumber</Name>
      <Value>12547896</Value>
    </DataItem>
    <DataItem>
      <Name>Agent_LastName</Name>
      <Value>Doe</Value>
    </DataItem>
 </DataItems>
....
```

I can loop through the nodes and find the node Agent_LastName

```
node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText == "Agent_LastName"
```

but I need the text that is in the Value tag directly after this node.
How can I step to the next node.

I could just set a flag set the flag when I find the node ant then on the next iteration grab the inner text but this seems sloppy.

Comment: `node.SelectSingleNode("Value").InnerText == "Cash" `doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Xpath

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.load(@"doc.xml");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
var node = root.SelectSingleNode("/DataFeedObject/DataItems/DataItem/[Name = 'Agent_LastName']/Value");
```

Comment: Ok I need a little bit more info.  I have created an xmlNode and I then try to SelectSingleNode() and I enter the path but get a error that the item is null

Comment: now getting the error Expression must evaluate to a node-set

Comment: If I try SelectSingleNode("//DataFeedObject/TransactionID").Value I get the value in the inner text, but when I try //DataFeedObject/DataItems/DataItem/[Name = 'Agent_LastName']).Value        I get the error Expression must evaluate to a node-set.    I assume this means that it cannot find the node with this path.

Comment: Nope still getting the same "Expression must evaluate to a node-set" error

Comment: I have read the article and I have tried your latest version and still get the same error.  if I use xpath and stop and dataItem it does not error.  If I look for just name it does not error, the moment I am looking for a specific name value I get the error.   One other thing is seeing that I need to get about 4 of these values out of the xml I am not sure if doing this would be as efficient and looping once through the document gather the data in one loop, which is working now.

Comment: The code in my answer was tested in Visual Studio 2015 with the XML you posted except I added a closing </DataFeedObject> tag. It does exactly what the question asked. If you need things with each of the nodes in turn then it is better to iterate through them.

Comment: I am sure it works, I think there is an issue with the xml. I have marked it as the answer

Answer (score -1):

After playing around a bit I found this which works

```
   if (node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText == "Agent_LastName")
    {
      string name = node.SelectSingleNode("Value").InnerText
    }
```

The only issue is I am only able to get this to work by iterating through all the nodes in the node list  "DataItems/DataItem".